# Errors while compiling MPI

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mpi

I am trying to compile a code in C++ using code from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953979/sending-and-receiving-array-using-mpi-part-2.

I use the following command to compile: `mpiicpc -o <filename> xxxx.cc -lmpi`

After I compile, all my errors seem to refer to the two functions i have defined in my source code to print output values and do the MPI Isend and MPI Irecv. Specifically, I get two types of errors

1. Error: Identifier "variable" is undefined
2. Error: Too few arguments in function call: `MPI_Isend/MPI_Irecv` and `MPI Waitall();`
   Finally, it exists with this message: compilation aborted for xxxx.cc (code 2).

Could you please point to what I must be doing wrong while defining the variables?

Here is an excerpt of my source code (The code in its entirety is available at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953979/sending-and-receiving-array-using-mpi-part-2):

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int my_rank;
int p;
int source; 
int dest;
int tag = 0;

//Allocating Memory
double *A = new double[Rows*sizeof(double)];
double *B = new double[Rows*sizeof(double)];
....
....
....

//MPI Commands
MPI_Status status;
MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);

//For number of beats

for (ibeat=0;ibeat<beats;ibeat++)
{
    for (i=0; i<Cols/2; i++)
    {
        for (y=0; y<Rows/2; y++)
        {
            if (my_rank == 0)
                if (i < 48)
                    if (y<48)
                       V[i][y] = 0;

            if (my_rank ==
              .....
                ....
                  ....        
        }
    }

    //Load the Array with the edge values
    for (r=0; r<Rows/2; y++)
    {
        if ((my_rank == 0) || (my_rank == 1))
        {
            A[r] = V[r][48];
            BB[r] = V[r][48];
        }

        if ((my_rank
            ...
            ...
    }

    prttofile ();
    outputpass ();
    ibeat = ibeat+1;
 }

 MPI_Finalize ();
}


void prttofile ()
{
for (i = 0; i<Cols/2; i++)
  {
    for (y = 0; y<Rows/2; y++)
    {
        if (my_rank == 0)
           fout << V[i][y] << " " ;
        ....
           .... 
    }
  }

if (my_rank == 0)
    fout << endl;
 ....
}


void outputpass ()
{
int test = 2;
if ((my_rank%test) == 0)
{
    MPI_Isend(C, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //Non blocking Send
    MPI_Irecv(CC, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); //Non Blocking Recv
}
else if ((my_rank%test) == 1)
....
....

MPI_Waitall ();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MPI_Isend()`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Isend.html) requires a lot more arguments than what you've supplied. Here's your line:

```
MPI_Isend(C, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Where's the tag? Where's the request?

Similarly, your [`MPI_Waitall()`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Waitall.html) doesn't have any arguments at all! You need the array of requests, the number of requests, and an array of statuses.

I suggest you read an example of non-blocking communication in MPI.

Answer (score 2):

1. You're not declaring a lot of variables - in particular the loop counters.  Declare them all at the top of your functions and you'll be fine.
2. According to [the documentation](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Isend.html), the signature of `MPI_Isend()` is:

   ```
   int MPI_Isend( void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest,
          int tag, MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Request *request )
   ```

   It has seven parameters - you are passing only five arguments.  You'll need to correct that.  The same goes for `MPI_Irecv()`.

Comment: Hi Carl,Thank you. (1) Do you mean I should declare them within the function? I thought declaring them inside main still renders them as Global Variables. (2) Thanks! (3) The two functions you indicate prttofile () and outputpass () are not defined within the main () routine. I just call those functions from within main. The line numbers on the errors seem to point to those functions I refer to from within main. Please feel to correct me. Thanks!

Comment: @Ashmohan Variables are only global when defined outside *all* functions. Variables in `main()` are local to `main()`.

Comment: @Ashmohan - 1: you need to declare them in an appropriate scope.  Global (outside of *any* function, including `main`) or local (inside the function where you use it).  3:  I was misreading something there - never mind!